# Maxdate not updating after app went in background for a couple days

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making an app with a datepicker and a maxdate that only work once meaning if app goes  in background for a couple of days my maxdate is not updating.
there most be a method that tell the app that it regain focus so that it check the maxdate.
thx in advance :)

Comment: Show your code which sets max date.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    
    NSLog(@"i pass thru viewwillappear");
    mySelectedDate.maximumDate = [NSDate date];

Comment: like i said the code works fine but only goes thru when app start fresh if stays in background 1 day maxdate should be +1 but date stays the 1 day old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application comes from background, the delegate method viewWillAppear will not be called. Rather you should do below thing.

At the time of reactivation, if you want to carry a particular thing for a viewcontroller, you should register a notification in its viewDidLaod method.

'UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification' will automatically notify your application and given controller, if they have registered for. So,add below code in your viewDidLoad method.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(setMaxDate)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Now write down the method,

```
-(void) setMaxDate
{
    mySelectedDate.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Do not forget to remove observer in dealloc method.

Comment: thank you very much its working fine but you raised another question...i do not have a dealloc method can you elaborate on that please

Comment: even if you are using ARC, you can write dealloc method. Write it and remove the observer from there only.

Comment: yes it worked fine my date is being updated when coming back from a long sleep in the background thank you very mucho

Comment: In that case you should up vote and accept the answer by clicking check mark on the left side of answer... That will help other users that, this is the correct way to do it..

Comment: its not working anymore....everytime my datepicker change date it only write the max date

Comment: it is not working anymore for some reason i have 2 addtarget 1 for the datepicker value change and 1 for a segment value change but after i incremented the notification all my other targets dont work